# Integrating tawk.to into Angular 6 (Angular 2) app

Tags: angular, tawk.to

I'd like to integrate tawk.to chat into my Angular 6 website.

Tawk.to provides the following code:

```
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script--> 
<script type="text/javascript"> var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date(); (function(){ var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s1.async=true; s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/17f35g40afc2c34e96e75909/default'; s1.charset='UTF-8'; s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*'); s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0); })(); </script> 
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

The code basically creates divs in my page:

[image]

But naturally when I navigate to another route the html widget gets destroyed.

I'm thinking of using a service for fetching the external script and a component for displaying the widget. But I'm not sure how well it is going to work.

What's the best approach to integrate tawk.to live chat into an angular app ?

Answer (score 3):

in case anyone else is struggling with this I managed to make some progress, my stack is ionic 5 and angular 8, first I created a component in charge of loading Tawk to my PWA, with this simple code

```
import {Component, Inject, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tawk-chat',
  templateUrl: './tawk-chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tawk-chat.component.scss'],
})
export class TawkChatComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id: string;
  script = this._renderer.createElement('script');

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document, ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.script.text = `var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {}, Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
    (function () {
      var s1 = document.createElement("script"), s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      s1.async = true;
      s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/${this.id}/default';
      s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
      s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
      s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
    })();`;
    this._renderer.appendChild(this._document.body, this.script);
  }
}
```

The referenced the component on my app.component.html like this

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet id="content1"></ion-router-outlet>
  <app-tawk-chat [id]="_enviroment.tawkId"></app-tawk-chat>
</ion-app>
```

Then found out from here https://www.tawk.to/knowledgebase/advanced-features/using-a-text-link-or-button-to-open-the-chat-widget/ that you can set the widget as hidden by default.

Finally, just call this function whenever you want to open the chat

```
openChat() {
    window.Tawk_API.maximize();
  }
```

Also, you can use this._window.Tawk_API to access any of the method defined on https://www.tawk.to/javascript-api/#onChatStarted

Only limitation that I'm still facing, is the following

1. Client opens the chat and sends a message
2. Operator receives the message and is typing a response
3. Client closes the chat before receiving response
4. operator sends the response
5. WebApp makes a soft click noise but no notification.

I guess I'll need to make some sort of workaround through push notification, so when an operator is chatting with someone and the person closes the chat, a notification is sent "manually"

Answer (score 0):

You can add script files in body tags at **index.html**

Adding CSS and JavaScript. The temptation is to add the external files directly to your index.html file.

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

     <!--Start of Tawk.to Script--> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date(); (function(){ var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s1.async=true; s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/17f35g40afc2c34e96e75909/default'; s1.charset='UTF-8'; s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*'); s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0); })(); </script> 
    <!--End of Tawk.to Script-->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Create your own [tawk.to account](https://dashboard.tawk.to/#/dashboard)

After you can receive some code form there like as
Once the code is active on your website, you will be able to chat with visitors.
then go to your  `index.html` and
Paste the code below on your website the before the `</body>` tag.

sample code

```
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/17f35g40afc2c34e96e75909/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

Comment: Hi, I created this question some time ago. But, firstly this is an angular related question. Secondly, this will created a widget in all pages, but I only needed it on certain routes (frontend user pages, but not on admin panel pages)

Comment: Hey, @sr9yar did you got something?

Comment: yea did anyone find out how to add on certain pages only?

Comment: I manage to make small progress by following https://github.com/rjcoupe/ngx-tawk I manage to show the chat only on certain pages, but when I navigate away the widget stills shown, now struggling to get it removed

Comment: @HardikMasalawala , Actuality i'm not used with angular 8

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy widget to index.html.
2. https://www.tawk.to/knowledgebase/advanced-features/using-a-text-link-or-button-to-open-the-chat-widget/ -> Set as hidden on load.
3. Go to your webpage on which you want Tawk.to integration.
4. `<a id="bottom-right-corner" href="javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())"></a>`
5. `#bottom-right-corner { position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; margin-bottom: 20px; //specify your margins, this is example. margin-right: 20px; }`
6. Done :)

Answer (score 0):

Integrating Tawk.to in the most basic way is easy: paste their widget code into your Index.cshtml file and it works. However, giving your Angular code the ability to interact with the widget through their Javascript API in order to send information about the current user or to disable to widget on certain pages was a little more challenging. Here's how I did it...

Remove the widget script from Index.cshtml file and create a `TawkService`. In its basic form, this service simply inserts the script into the app on demand and keeps a reference to it:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/common";
import { Inject, Injectable, Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from "@angular/core";

declare var Tawk_API: any;

@Injectable()
export class TawkService {

    private loaded: boolean;private renderer: Renderer2;

    constructor(
        private rendererFactory: RendererFactory2,
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document) {
            this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
            this.load();
        }

    private load(){
        if(this.loaded)
            return;

        const s = this.renderer.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.text = `WIDGET_SCRIPT`;
        this.renderer.appendChild(this._document.body, s);
        Tawk_API.onLoad = this.loadedEvent.bind(this);
    }

    private loadedEvent(){
        this.loaded = true;
    }
}
```

Renderer2 can’t be injected into a service so you need to use the RendererFactory2.The service can be used in exactly the same way as you are using any other, after you have added it as a provider in your App.module.ts file:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        Components.entryComponents,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        TawkService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

After being imported into any of your components the service will create an instance of the widget on load, there will only be one instance of this service per lifetime scope so we don’t have to worry about multiple instances. I added a loaded property which is updated when the Tawk API raises an onLoad event to ensure we know when the widget has been created.

I wanted to use the setAttributes function which allows you to update the current user’s name, email and other metadata in Tawk. Calling this using the saved reference we have is easy enough but it won’t work unless Tawk has finished loading. To get around this I created a wrapper function that listens to an RXJS Observable and waits for the loaded property to change to true before calling any method.

```
private loadSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

private loadedEvent(){
    this.loaded = true;
    this.loadSubject.next(this.loaded);
}

public UpdateTawkUser(user: any) {
    this.loadedWrapper(() => {this.updateAtrributes(user)});
}

private loadedWrapper(func: any){ 
    if(!this.loaded){
        var sub = this.loadSubject.asObservable().subscribe({
            next: () => {
                func();
                sub.unsubscribe();
            },
            error: () => {}
            });
    } else {
        func();
    }
}

private updateAtrributes(user: any){
    Tawk_API.setAttributes({
        'name'  : `${user.firstname} ${user.surname}`,
        'email' : user.email,
        'id'  : user.id,
    }, function(error){});
}
```

Wrapping all calls to the API ensures we will do whatever needs to be done as soon as the chat widget is loaded and ready. I used this is a similar way for hiding chat on certain pages:

```
public SetChatVisibility(show: boolean = false) {
        this.loadedWrapper(() => show ? Tawk_API.showWidget() : Tawk_API.hideWidget());
    }
```

You can import the service in the desired component and set it to hide in ngOnInit() and to show in ngOnDestroy() so that it reappers when the user navigates away. Without the wrapper we would be calling these methods too early:

```
export class NoChatComponent extends CoreComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ComponentCanDeactivate {

    constructor(
        private TawkService: TawkService
    ) {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.TawkService.SetChatVisibility(false);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.TawkService.SetChatVisibility(true);
    }
}
```

My full code is available here: https://gist.github.com/jamesmundy/c73a07cc7276e8e6b32102e9ecb7b063